# What is the point of passing the value to another method when the values are distinct?

Tags: java, methods

Take for example the code below, what is the point of passing the value of "name" to the method changeName when the parameters get completely change in the changeName method?

```
public class PassString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Shakespeare";

        System.out.println("In main, the name is" + name);

        //What is the point of passing the variable to a new method
        changeName(name);

        System.out.println("In main, the name is now" + name);

    }

    public static void changeName(String str)
    {
        str = "Dickens";

        System.out.println("In changeName, the name is now" + str);
    }



}
```

Comment: cuz **you cannot predict the future** I guess

Answer (score 1):

*[Pedagogical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedagogical)*. I believe it is meant to demonstrate that the `String`'s reference from `main()` was not altered by the assignment in `changeName`.

Comment: I guess the op is asking about something else

Comment: @KickButtowski Sorry, but given the print before, during and after calling `changeName`, I think this is the only explanation.

Comment: What is the point of passing the value to another method when the values are distinct?

Comment: @KickButtowski *Shakespeare* vs *Dickens*. Why pass "Shakespeare" when it will be replaced by "Dickens". Why indeed.

Comment: Agree to disagree is beauty of living in great USA

Comment: @KickButtowski nope I don't think switching from name to str is his issue.  I think Frisch has it right.  Collin is asking what is the point of passing the value of "name".  Collin is right. It's pointless.  Frisch is right.  Being pointless was the point.  Hopefully, only educators write such silly methods.

Answer (score 0):

This `changeName` method is useless, so there is no point in passing it anything or even calling it. It does nothing beyond printing. It can't change the String reference passed to it.

The `str = "Dickens";` assignment only changes a local reference, and does not change the `name` reference passed by the caller of `changeName`.

Comment: I guess the op is asking about something else